# LINQ method syntax to group by a column, pick one element from each group with total count per group

Tags: c#, .net, linq, fluent

I am looking for a LINQ query using the method syntax to group by a column, pick the first member of each group and add total count of each group into the selected entities of each group.

Is there a way to achieve this in a single elegant statement in LINQ method syntax?

Input:

```
OrderId  Name       Category
=============================
1        Sam        X
2        Sam        Y
3        Matthew    A
4        Matthew    B
```

Output:

```
OrderId  Name       Category    Count
======================================
1        Sam        X           2
4        Matthew    B           2
```

Something like this. The value of category is irrelevant to me, I just want to get any element from the group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be as simple as a `GroupBy` with a *projection* and some *aggregates*

```
var results  = someList
      .Group(x => x.Name)
      .Select(x => new Entity()
         {
            Name = x.Key,
            OrderId = x.First().OrderId,
            Category = x.First().Category,  
            Count = x.Count()
         });
```